# Grouping Timestamps based on the interval between them

Tags: sql, session, select, group-by, hive

I have a table in Hive (SQL) with a bunch of timestamps that need to be grouped in order to create separate sessions based on the time difference between the timestamps.

Example:
Consider the following timestamps(Given in HH:MM for simplicity):

`9.00
9.10
9.20
9.40
9.43
10.30
10.45
11.25
12.30
12.33`
and so on..

So now, all timestamps that fall within 30 mins of the next timestamp come under the same session,
i.e. 9.00,9.10,9.20,9.40,9.43 form 1 session.

But since the difference between 9.43 and 10.30 is more than 30 mins, the time stamp 10.30 falls under a different session. Again, 10.30 and 10.45 fall under one session.

After we have created these sessions, we have to obtain the minimum timestamp for that session and the max timestamp.

I tried to subtract the current timestamp with its LEAD and place a flag if it is greater than 30 mins, but I'm having difficulty with this.

Any suggestion from you guys would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if the question isn't clear enough.

Expected Output for this sample data:

```
Session_start   Session_end
9.00                9.43
10.30               10.45
11.25               11.25 (same because the next time is not within 30 mins)
12.30               12.33
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Pls post your table structure with sample data and expected output

Comment: @Akhil Please check now

Comment: @FenderBender We've checked. No change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So it's not MySQL but Hive. I don't know Hive, but if it supports LAG, as you say, try this PostgreSQL query. You will probably have to change the time difference calculation, that's usually different from one dbms to another.

```
select min(thetime) as start_time, max(thetime) as end_time
from
(
  select thetime, count(gap) over (rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as groupid
  from
  (
    select thetime, case when thetime - lag(thetime) over (order by thetime) > interval '30 minutes' then 1 end as gap
    from mytable
  ) times
) groups
group by groupid
order by min(thetime);
```

The query finds gaps, then uses a running total of gap counts to build group IDs, and the rest is aggregation.

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8bc4a/6.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
SELECT MIN(session_time_tmp) session_start, MAX(session_time_tmp) session_end FROM 
(
SELECT  IF((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(your_time_field, COALESCE(@previousValue, your_time_field))) / 60) > 30 , 
        @sessionCount := @sessionCount + 1, @sessionCount ) sessCount, 
        ( @previousValue := your_time_field ) session_time_tmp  FROM 
(
SELECT your_time_field, @previousValue:= NULL, @sessionCount := 1 FROM yourtable ORDER BY your_time_field
) a
) b
GROUP BY sessCount
```

Just replace ***yourtable*** and ***your_time_field***

Comment: Wow, impressive use of variables. I should practise this :-) Your answer would have been even better, had you explained what your query is doing, though.

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenKettner. Sorry for the lack of explanation. The fact is that I tried to explain, but failed to do that effectively !!. So I would recommend learn_it_yourself method here by extracting each query :)

Answer (score 2):

With MySQL lacking LAG and LEAD functions, getting the previous or next record is some work already. Here is how:

```
select 
  thetime, 
  (select max(thetime) from mytable afore where afore.thetime < mytable.thetime) as afore_time,
  (select min(thetime) from mytable after where after.thetime > mytable.thetime) as after_time
from mytable;
```

Based on this we can build the whole query where we are looking for gaps (i.e. the time difference to the previous or next record is more than 30 minutes = 1800 seconds).

```
select
  startrec.thetime as start_time,
  (
    select min(endrec.thetime) 
    from 
    (
      select 
        thetime, 
        coalesce(time_to_sec(timediff((select min(thetime) from mytable after where after.thetime > mytable.thetime), thetime)), 1801) > 1800 as gap
      from mytable
    ) endrec
    where gap
    and endrec.thetime >= startrec.thetime
  ) as end_time
from
(
  select 
    thetime, 
    coalesce(time_to_sec(timediff(thetime, (select max(thetime) from mytable afore where afore.thetime < mytable.thetime))), 1801) > 1800 as gap
  from mytable
) startrec
where gap;
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d307b/20.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comprehensive answer.
And we can actually use lead and lag, I apologize sincerely for this confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MIN(STR_TO_DATE(B.column1, '%H.%i')), '%H.%i') AS Session_start, 
       DATE_FORMAT(MAX(STR_TO_DATE(B.column1, '%H.%i')), '%H.%i') AS Session_end
FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT A.column1, diff, IF(@diff:=diff < 30, @id, @id:=@id+1) AS rnk
            FROM (SELECT B.column1, TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(B.column1, '%H.%i'), STR_TO_DATE(A.column1, '%H.%i'))) / 60 AS diff
                  FROM tableA A
                  INNER JOIN tableA B ON STR_TO_DATE(A.column1, '%H.%i') < STR_TO_DATE(B.column1, '%H.%i') 
                  GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE(A.column1, '%H.%i')
                 ) AS A, (SELECT @diff:=0, @id:= 1) AS B
           ) AS B ON A.column1 = B.column1
GROUP BY IFNULL(B.rnk, 1);
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a7fe8/5)

**OUTPUT**

```
| SESSION_START | SESSION_END |
|---------------|-------------|
|          9.00 |        9.43 |
|         10.30 |       10.45 |
|         11.25 |       11.25 |
|         12.30 |       12.33 |
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.
But im afraid this wont work when in this case:
`
9.00
9.03
9.10
9.55
10.00`

Now, 9.00 to 9.10 is one session and 9.55 to 10.00 is another since the difference between 9.10 to 9.55 exceeds 30 mins.

Comment: @SaharshShah. You may check it yourself . http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb346/1 . All I did was to change from 10 30 to 10 05. Buddy, my point to Pankaj was not to put you down, but it is wrong to do marketing here for votes :-). Hope you get it

Comment: @Akhil if someone doing good job and spending time here we have to appreciate and giving him bonus point.